# How do you delegate class methods to another object in Ruby using the Forwardable Module?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to delegate a class method on Bar to an instance of the Foo class, but I can't get the delegation to work. None of the delegated methods throw an error, the getters simply return nil. Here's what my code looks like:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :worksheet_id, :access_token

  def configure worksheet_id: raise, access_token: raise
    @worksheet_id = worksheet_id
    @access_token = access_token
  end
end

class Bar
  class << self
    extend Forwardable
    def_delegators Foo.new, :configure, :worksheet_id, :access_token
  end

  configure worksheet_id: 1, access_token: 2
end
```

And here's what I'd like to be able to do.

```
Bar.worksheet_id # => returns nil, should be 1.
Bar.access_token # => returns nil, should be 2.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: the tests at the end describe what should happen. I'll make that clearer in the question.

Comment: see here `http://ruby-doc.org//stdlib-2.0/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html` . also there seem to be something wrong with your class/instance scopes. I suggest you describe the problem you try solve a little more (not the technical part).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to the `def_delegator` family of methods is a `Symbol` or `String` (or anything else that implements `to_s`) that denotes the "accessor" by which to access the delegation target. It is *not* the delegation target itself.

So, something like this will work:

```
class Bar
  class << self
    extend Forwardable
    def_delegators :@foo, :configure, :worksheet_id, :access_token
  end

  @foo = Foo.new

  configure worksheet_id: 1, access_token: 2
end

Bar.worksheet_id # => 1
Bar.access_token # => 2
```

What actually happens, is that the `forwardable` library uses string interpolation to build definitions for forwarder methods, which are then `eval`d.

In essence, it looks like this:

```
"#{target}.__send__(#{method})"
```

So, you can pass anything as `target`, whose `to_s` results in something that you can `eval` and then call `__send__` on. However, in your case, `Foo.new.to_s` is something like `#<Foo:0x007fc4aa521ab8>`. When interpolated into the string and `eval`d, the line starts with a `#` character, or simply put: the forwarder method consists of a single line which is commented out! And that's why it returns `nil`, because that's what an empty method returns.

Comment: Hi Jorg, what's the reason you extend the metaclass with `Forwardable`, rather than just extending the class itself?

Comment: @Jonah: Because that's what's in the question. The OP wants to forward methods of the singleton class, not methods of the class.